# Metadata API returns UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. when uploading zip

Tags: metadata-api

When uploading a zip with custom objects, layouts, profiles, and permission sets the Metadata API returns the following error.

> UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1123676363-XXXXX (-1340066242)

The zip file is generated by a tool and works for other orgs. The zip uses UTF-8 as the alternate filename encoding.
What are possible causes for a zip upload failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce support can assist with reporting on the details of this error to find a cause.

They reported that the exception was `MalformedInputException` during the decompression of the zip.
On further inspecting the files, a profile name had a non-ASCII character, `ü`, in it.
After removing the special character from the name of the profile, the zip uploaded successfully.
I asked them to report this as an issue.